# how to delete files and subfolder using bat file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Please help me to delete all files and sub folder in MYFILES folder. Below is my code (it is delete MYFILES too but i want to keep it):

```
rmdir e:\MYFILES\ /s /q
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
set targetdir=c:\example
del /q %targetdir%\*
for /d %%x in (%targetdir%\*) do @rd /s /q ^"%%x^"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is  wonderfull, that's all for me. Thank you both of you, Good man!

Comment: Whenever you get the answer to your question, Accept it as answer so that it can help others in future.

Comment: i am new member of stackoverflow.. and now i understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
pushd "e:\MYFILES" && ( rmdir . /s /q 2>nul & popd )
```

Change to the desired folder (`pushd`). If the command was successful (the `&&` is an equivalent to *if there are no errors*), the folder is now the current active directory, so, remove anything inside it (`rmdir . /s /q`) As it is the current directory, it can not be deleted (the `2>nul` hides the error output when the current folder can not be removed). Once the process ends, return to the previous active directory (`popd`)